# Getting estimation for the coefficients of a linear combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, normed-spaces

I have come across these types of problems. Do you aware of any papers or books somehow related?

Let $v_{1},\dots, v_{n}$ be vectors in the plane such that $\|v_{1}+ \dots + v_{n}\|$ is small and let $\lambda_{1},\dots, \lambda_{n}$ be positive real variables such that $\|\lambda_{1} v_{1}+ \dots +\lambda_{n}v_{n}\|$ is relatively large and  $\lambda_{1}+\dots+\lambda_{n}$ is fixed. Now we want to get estimations for the coefficients $\lambda_i$.

Comment: do you know the individual values of the $v_{i}$ ?

Comment: @markleeds Yes we know the values of $v_i$. Even the case that they have length one is important to me.

Comment: For instance you can assume that $v_k$ is very close to $\exp(2\pi i k/n)$.

Comment: I think it's  a non-linear optimization because you minimizing a norm. Any type of variable metric ( BFGS ) algorithm should be able to handle that, I would think.

Comment: Thanks. It seems good.

Comment: There are many different variable metric approaches but I think BFGS is the most popular one.